# How to upload video using Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, video, model-view-controller, upload

I tried to upload a **`.wmv`** format but I got this error `"Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object"`. It works in image files but not in videos.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'videos/upload', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) }}                               
{{ Form::file('video',null) }}  
{{ Form::submit('Upload') }}
{{ Form::close() }}

------

$videofile = Input::file('video')->getClientOriginalName();
Input::file('video')->move('uploads/video', $videofile);

if (Input::hasFile('video')){
return Redirect::to('videos');
}
```

Comment: .wav files are audio files not video it should be noted

Comment: @RachelGallen I used .wmv format not .wav file. thanks

Comment: oh misread your code its hard to make out with the text so tiny!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the expression `'files=> true'` to the end of your first line of code and it should work for you